# Plotly: How to display a bar chart over a scatter plot?

Tags: javascript, plotly

I'm using plotly.js to do some data visualization. I need to display an opaque filled-area scatter plot behind a bar chart - something like [this](https://www.steema.com/uploads/products/bar-area34.png) - but no matter how much I play with the bar chart's opacity or the order of my data array, the filled-area plot is placed on top of the bar chart.

This is what my code looks like:

```
<script> 
var trace2 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
  y: [120, 180, 290, 150, 110], 
  name: 'Type 1', 
  type: 'bar'
};

var trace5 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
  y: [75, 48, 38, 61, 52],
  name: 'Type 2', 
  fill: 'tozeroy',
  fillcolor: 'rgb(235, 185, 10)',
  type: 'scatter',
  mode: 'none'
};

var data1 = [trace5, trace2];
var layout = {
  xaxis: {
    showdividers: true,
    dividercolor: 'grey',
    dividerwidth: 2
  },
  yaxis: {title: '<b>Data</b>', side: 'right'}
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data1, layout);
</script>
```